# D3.js, trouble initiating shp2json - encoding-indexes error

Tags: d3.js, encoding, shapefile

I'm trying to follow the tutorial Mike Bostock did for [Command Line Cartography](https://medium.com/@mbostock/command-line-cartography-part-1-897aa8f8ca2c#.wkwy54o6n) (which is a great help). Right after installing [shapefile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shapefile) and running the shp2json step [shp2json cb_2014_06_tract_500k.shp -o ca.json] I get this error message:
“error: Decoder not present. Did you forget to include encoding-indexes.js first?” an error message which originates from the [text-encoding](https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-encoding) package from NPM.

In trying to diagnoise the problem, I figured I should manually install text-encoding as it's in the shp2json dependency list but, didn't appear to be loading. I also reinstalled node to downgrade from 7.3.0 to 6.9.2 and a number of other things (my hacking around looking for a solution for a few hours) but, am stuck. Is this just a matter of updating a package.json?

I’m using Windows7, the env variables is set I believe correctly to \Users\myAccount\AppData\Roaming\npm. I’ve installed all packages globally as well. Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem when running the "#prepublish" script [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/670b9fe0577a29c39a1803f59c628769). Then I noticed that Mike's [shapefile repo](https://github.com/mbostock/shapefile) has this information in the README:

```
# shp2json --encoding *encoding*

Specify the dBASE table file character encoding. Defaults to “windows-1252”.
```

So I experimented and changed that script to:

```
shp2json --encoding utf-8 cb_${YEAR}_${STATE}_tract_500k.shp
```

*Note that in this line above my state and year variables had been defined higher in the script (I was using Texas[48], not California[06]).*

Also, I was getting another error asking for [d3-array](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-array). So I installed that, too.

Problem solved (at least in terms of processing the data and getting it to render in the browser). Others issues, like projection, remain. [Obviously](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyQaF.jpg).